# Incorrect results in probability calculation

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

By my calculations

```
roll[dice_,target_]:=
    Probability[
        target<= Max[x[#]&/@{1,dice}] || MemberQ[x[#]&/@{1,dice},0],
        Table[x[i]\[Distributed]DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0,9}],{i,1,dice}]];
N@roll[#, 4] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4} // TableForm
```

should produce

```
{0.7, 0.91, 0.94, 0.99}
```

but instead produces

```
{0.6, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84}
```

where, `0.6` and `0.84` are, confusingly, the correct values for a `target` of 5 (not 4) and `dice` of 1 and 2.

What's going in here? Even if I've got the lumbers wrong, the last three entries in the result shouldn't be the same.

Comment: What is the event for which you are calculating the probability? That would be important to check your implementation.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `x[#] & /@ Range[1, dice]`, or the equivalent but more readable `Array[x, dice]`? The expression you have `x[#] & /@ {1, 4}` translates to `{x[1], x[4]}`, not `{x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]}`.

Comment: It seems that `MemberQ[x[#] & /@ {1, dice}, 0]` is always `False` so that leaves `Probability[4 <= Max[x[1], x[j]], Table[x[i] \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 9}], {i, 1, j}]]`.  That results in 3/5 = 0.6 when `j = 1` and 21/25 = 0.84 when `j > 1`.

Comment: You have not told us what you want the code to do. Without knowing what you are trying to do, we are guessing and basing our guesses on code that you say doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Closing a Mathematica question because the answer can be "found in the documentation" makes no sense to anyone who has ever tried to use Wolfram's documentation or APIs.

Comment: It is sometimes the best option for closing questions that involve user error, insofar as it comes closest to describing the reason. I realize sometimes the errors can be subtle and fall outside the realm of "simple mistake". But this question was not without flaws. Also some straightforward (if tedious) debug-by-`Print`-statements would likely have uncovered the problems, and no effort in that direction was indicated. (I realize maybe you tried that and came up short. Going forward, if that is the case it would be good to mention it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what I think your code should do, according to my intuition:

```
Clear[roll]
roll[dice_, target_] :=
  Probability[
    Or @@ Join[{target <= Max@Array[x, dice]}, Thread[Array[x, dice] == 0]],
    Table[x[i] \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 9}], {i, 1, dice}]
  ];
 
N@roll[#, 4] & /@ Range[4]

(* Out: {0.7, 0.91, 0.973, 0.9919} *)
```

- Change `x[#] & /@ {1, dice}` to `Array[x, dice]`; `{1, dice}` is different from `Range[1, dice]` (= `{1, 2, 3, ... dice}`). For `dice = 4`, for instance, you were generating `Max[{x[1], x[4]}]` instead of `Max[{x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]}]`; the latter is almost certainly what you meant.
- The `MemberQ` expression does not work as a condition. I understood it to mean that any one of the `x[i]` could be zero. To express that, generate explicit non-zero equational conditions on each `x[i]`: `x[1] == 0 || x[2] == 0 || ...`.

Answer (score 5):

This is an order statistic question. So use it. For $dice$>1:

```
roll[dice_,target_]:=Module[{x,y},
Probability[target<=y||x==0,{x,y}\[Distributed]OrderDistribution[{DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0,9}],dice},{1,dice}]]]
```

The $dice$=1 case is left as a trivial exercise.